# why are integers considered as an ADT?

Tags: data-structures

According to the definition of ADT on wikipedia , it is given that ADT is a mathematical model for data types , And as per wikipedia, definition of mathematical model says that it is composed of variables and relationships.
Relationships can be described by operators, such as algebraic operators, functions, differential operators, etc. Variables are abstractions of system parameters of interest, that can be quantified.

Now I can get the intution that variables we can although define operations like addition , subtraction over integers but then how come they can be quantified ?

It's hard for me to get the basic understanding of this terminology used

Now this is the definition of quantification ,Approximation of a subjective aspect (attribute, characteristic, property) of a thing or phenomenon into numbers through an arbitrary scale (such as the Likert scale). Every aspect of nature can be quantified although it may not be measurable.

so how can integers be approximated when they don't have decimal parts

Comment: Are we talking Abstract Data Type, or Algebraic Data Type?

Comment: Integers are approximated in the sense that their representation in the computer is, by force, limited. I.e., 32 bits, not as large as you please.

Comment: Abstract data types only

Comment: So can you explain in layman terms what in general is an ADT , I am not getting the definition as stated by wikipedia